# It is not easy to see your previous comments

Tags: discussion, support, comments

It is easy to see your answers and questions from the user interface.

It is not easy to see your old comments.

Is it a way to do so? if no, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can see your comments on your activity tab: https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/28474/ppr?tab=activity&sort=comments - this is not as sophisticated as views on Qs and As, because you can only see them ordered from newest to oldest, but they should all be there.

Answer (score 2):

**TL; DR:**

Use this [site](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/155827/find-all-comments-ordered-by-votes) for viewing all your comments sorted by their score.

1. Input your user ID (hint: [what is my user id?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98771/what-is-my-user-id))
2. Enter "TeX" in the input box saying "search by name or url"

---

Unfortunately, the profile section does not display the comments sorted by their scores.

However, StackExchange kindly provides the [StackExchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) which lets you run custom SQL queries against their data sources.

Here is a simple query I made, which shows all your comments sorted by their votes: 
http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/155827/find-all-comments-ordered-by-votes

Comment: nice idea, but it doesn't seem to accept user ids that have spaces in them.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Your user ID is *not* your user name. See also ["what is my user ID?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98771/what-is-my-user-id). Yours is 579.

Comment: thanks.  i guess i'm just being dense.  (already this morning, i've managed to "break" the instructions for a new scanner, the problem being that some vital steps were left out of the instructions.  that has wasted several hours for me, but also for the person responsible for (re)writing the instructions.)  your query works -- but only for comments that do have votes; if votes = 0, comments aren't listed, but i guess those usually aren't the ones that one is looking for.

Comment: @barbarabeeton No problem, everyone encounters such days :) Are you sure that comments with a score of 0 aren't listed? Just scroll down the long list until the `score` field is literally empty.

Comment: well, i can't *ever* be absolutely certain (as i said, i have a history of breaking things, often as the result of scrupulously following incomplete or faulty instructions), but the scroll bar ends at the bottom of my screen (after maybe 20 comments), and won't go further, and the lowest vote count shown is 6.  i didn't see any option to "show more".  i *must* be missing something, but what?

Comment: @barbarabeeton That's really strange. Try using a different browser. This is what I see: http://i.imgur.com/vtY9cXB.png.

Comment: i usually use firefox (maybe not the most current: 25.0), so i'm trying explorer.  abject failure -- spins its wheels (after making me type in my information three times), and wipes everything out except for the red braces that identify the site.  and it just shut down the video card in my workstation (well, it's been dying anyhow, but the "management" can't come up with a satisfactory flat-screen monitor, so i'm still using a 21in crt).  okay, seamonkey delivers the goods.  thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: suggestion to you: when i change the site info, it wipes out my user id.  would be nice if it didn't.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I'm glad that it finally worked. Well, it's not my site, the service is provided by Stack Exchange (the company behind all these StackOverflow sister sites). You might want to post a feature request at [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=data-explorer) or directly dig into the [code](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer) ;)